# Read a special character in iso-8859-1 and get utf-8 value of same character

Tags: java, character-encoding

So I have a string: CIUDAD DE M**É**XICO which is in Latin-1 encoding in its source (sql server database). I need to read this string and convert the same string to utf-8 format in java.
So my input= CIUDAD DE MÉXICO (Latin-1)
my output = CIUDAD DE MÉXICO (utf-8)

I tried doing

```
 System.out.println(new String(myStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
```

But this returns me CIUDAD DE M�XICO  since the character É converts to something different in utf8-1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are you using encoding as UTF8-1 instead of "UTF-8" ?

Comment: The JDBC driver will take care of the database encoding, so you just go get the string from there, e.g. `String s = resultSet.getString(1)`. Similarly, `System.out` should already know the encoding of the output, so you just go print that string, e.g. `System.out.println(s)`. If the string `s` in memory is not correct (as seen by a *debugger*), check the JDBC driver options. If the printed output is not correct, change the default character set using the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` command-line option.

Comment: Your code doesn't run: `UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF8-1`

Comment: "I need to read this string and convert the same string to utf-8 format in java." That requirement doesn't make sense, and suggests a misunderstanding of how strings work in Java. There's no such thing as "a string in UTF-8 format". Every string is just a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas already gave most information you need.

Yes, we all know that character encodings can be nasty little bastards.

First of all, Strings don't have encodings, they either contain the correct characters or they don't. Encodings are necessary when you convert between Strings and byte arrays or byte streams.

> new String(myStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8")

does something weird, but not a useful conversion of encodings: you take the String `myStr`, convert it to a byte array containing the ISO-8859-1 encoding of your characters.

Then you read these bytes into a String, declaring these bytes weren't ISO-8859-1 encoded, but UTF-8. That's simply wrong, as you created the bytes with a different encoding.

Then you do a `System.out.println()` of the results.

What can go wrong?

- Is the `myStr` value correct, coming from the database? Look at it e.g. in a debugger. You should see an É character (decimal value 201 / hex 0xC1) at the correct position. If not, have a look at the database driver settings.
- Does your console output show characters correctly? Try `System.out.println("CIUDAD DE M\u00c1XICO");`. That should give the correct name with the accented E. If not, it's not your program's fault, but Java and the console window don't agree on the character encoding. That's often the case with the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`. Look at the output e.g. in the Eclipse console window and ignore the other, broken console...

Where do you want the UTF-8 encoded result?

- A String? As strings don't have encodings, just characters, you need not do anything.
- A file? Open it with UTF-8 as the encoding.
- A byte array? Create it with UTF-8 as the encoding.
- A database column? Make sure the driver's settings are OK, and just pass the string.